# How to find a number which is less than and closest to number X in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, search

For example I have array:

```
Array(
  [0] => 15
  [1] => 6
  [2] => 19
  [3] => 21
  [4] => 18
)
```

If current time is 20 then I need value 19 (which is less than and near to 20)

similarly if I pass my X number as 17 it will return 15 from array.

If 7 then it should return 6.

Please suggest how to achieve that with PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: How far have you tried?

Comment: I tried by passing ( < ) condition in code from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147356/find-number-which-is-greater-than-or-equal-to-n-in-an-array but it did not return small value than my number , any suggestion what I am doing wrong ?  
I am not sure but I think something need to be changed with end($array)

Comment: What if user pass `15` then what will be the required answer

Comment: Then it will be less than 15 which is 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your custom function using `array_filter` and `end` function like as

```
function find_closest($arr,$x){
    sort($arr);
    $filtered_array = array_filter($arr,function($v)use($x){ 
        return $v < $x;
    });
    return count($filtered_array) > 0 ? end($filtered_array) : "Your Message";
}

echo find_closest($arr,17);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/457558)

Comment: Thanks :) its working as it is  supposed to be, can you please also suggest solution if there is no lesser value in the array. To illustrate I passed 6 but there is no smaller number than 6 in array so I want to pass some default value , how can we do that ?

Comment: ok I can do that by checking result if there is something then its ok otherwise if its empty I will pass by own value. Thanks a lot for solution :)

Comment: Thanks for your all help but to be fair I have to accept other guys answer as its more cleaner and faster. But this code also works great and according to requirement.

Comment: Check [my_answer speed](https://3v4l.org/JgmmD/perf#tabs) and [shock_gone_wild answer speed](https://3v4l.org/ka9rF/perf#tabs) @jas

Comment: wow @Uchiha thats great! Really great effort to check performances and making things clear. I am very thankful to all of you guys doing efforts and help for this.

Comment: @shock_gone_wild that can be the case at far more bigger arrays. But not within this case

Comment: Well, i think that the solution should satisfy any kind of input arrays. But anyway. I think both solutions are good and performance time does not matter seriously here..

Comment: I am not sure what to do please let me know I will accept it accordingly. I really appreciate your efforts @  [shock-gone-wild](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3927116/shock-gone-wild) and @ [Uchiha](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2899618/uchiha)

Comment: Just choose the answer you are most comfortable with. It's really up to you. Maybe you should take Uchihas one, as he was first to give the right answer

Answer (score 1):

I would do it the following way. I think that's a little cleaner (and probably faster) than the accepted answer:

```
function closest($arr, $x) {
    $result = "default";
    sort($arr);

    foreach($arr as $value) {
        if($value < $x) {
            $result = $value;
        } else
            break;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Great thank you, its also working according to my requirements but I am not sure which one is better,off-course it looks cleaner but as you said this  its more faster. So Should I go for this one !

Answer (score -1):

Push the element that you're trying to find, in your array.

```
array_push($your_array, "17");
$arr = asort($your_array);
$key = array_search('17', $arr);
```

The value will be in **$arr[$key-1]**. 
Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for you help but its not working as per my requirement and answer by @Uchiha is working.