# Matching a closest number

Tags: php, math

I have a series of numbers from 0 to 59 which are listed to a given step value. For example if I have Step value is 5 then the series become.

0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55

(or if the Step was 3, it'd become 0, 3, 6, 9, 12 .... 59 etc etc)

Now I need to find the closest match on a given user number. For example, if I the user number 18,19 or 20 then the closest match is 20. If the user number is 16,17 then it's 15.
I am assuming this examples for step value of 5. But if it could be for any step value, then that would be great.

How do I do that?

```
$step = 5; 
$usernumber = 18;
$myseries = range(0, 59, $step);
foreach($myseries as $num) {
  echo $num.'<br />';

  //if($usernumber is close to $num) { 
  //      echo 'Matching number is '.$num;
  //}
}
```

Comment: Is step value will be fix ? Who will decide step value ? how it will going to change ?

Comment: yes it will be fixed ... e.g. $step = 5; Updated code above.

Comment: Than see this question I guess is the same what you need..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464919/php-nearest-value-from-an-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about `$step * round($usernumber / $step)` ?

You will need to check bounds of `$usernumber` and give it as a floating-point number for the division.

Comment: Great - looks like this is what I need. Let me test.

Comment: this smashes any loop attempt, smart

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$step = 5; 
$usernumber = 188;
$myseries = range(0, 59, $step);

$myseries = range(0, 59, 5);

$check = round($usernumber/$step) * $step;

if(in_array($check,$myseries))
    echo "<br>".$check;
else
    echo max($myseries);
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/Ia4gM)

Answer (score 0):

If your series won't have any holes (like `8, 9, 11`), then you don't need to iterate through the whole array. It is only a draft, so not sure if it's 100% correct, but I hope it can help:

```
$usernumber = 18;
$min = 0;
$max = 60;
$step = 5;

$r = $usernumber % $step;
if ($r > $step / 2) {
    $num = $usernumber + ($step - $r);
    if ($num > $max) {
        $num = $max - $max % $step;
    }
}
else {
    $num = $usernumber - ($step - $r);
    if ($num < $min) {
        $num = $min + $step - ($min % $step);
    }
}
echo $num;
```