# PHP Searching an array in descent from needle

Tags: php, arrays, search

I'm trying to write a sort of nearest number chunk of code similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464919/php-nearest-value-from-an-array) except that I do not want my code to return any values greater than the needle.

Basically you have an array of values:

```
$array = array(2012, 2013, 2015, 2016, 2018);
```

And the function would have these results

```
    needle: 2011  result: 2012
    needle: 2012  result: 2012
    needle: 2014  result: 2013
```

I was thinking something along these lines:

```
while(!in_array($year, $years))
{
    if($year<$years[count($years)+1]){$year = $years[$count($years)+1];}//Edited 
    $year -= 1;
}
```

<s>Except that does not catch the exception of 2011 being less than all of the values in the array</s>

Edit, I figured out how to catch the exception of 2011, now my only issue is that this just seems inefficient if say the year 3012 were to be entered php would run through ~1000 iterations of the code.

Comment: Given needle is `2011` and the lowest value is `2012`, and you posit that it shouldn't return a value greater than needle, why is it returning `2012`? Shouldn't it return `null` or `-1` or something?

Comment: I suppose it should, however I wanted there to always to be a returned number and if the needle is less then the value of the smallest array value, there would be no actual response. Basically in my application the returned value goes into a MySQLi query and I wanted as little chance for error as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code example could become very expensive for big arrays. It's better to avoid cycling through the array more than once, which is what in_array() would have to do behind the scenes.

Try this:

```
function nearest(array $arr, $needle) {
    $closest = current($arr);

    foreach ($arr as $val) {
        if ($val === $needle) {
            return $val; // found it :)
        }

        if ($val > $closest && $val < $needle) {
            // we found something closer and less than the needle, so use it
            $closest = $val;
        }
    }
    // we've reached the end, so return the closest solution
    return $closest;
}
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick. I completely agree that using a while loop can be very costly with the code. Thanks for telling me about what in_array() would be doing behind the scenes, I guess that I hadn't really thought of how php generates the result for in_array(). :)

Answer (score 0):

I've created a function for you. Try to use it.

```
function get_nearest($array, $needle){

    $answer = FALSE ;
    $diff   = FALSE ;

    foreach($array as $arr){
        $temp_diff = abs($arr-$needle) ;

        if($diff === FALSE || $temp_diff < $diff){
            $answer = $arr ;
            $diff   = $temp_diff ;
        }
    }

    return $answer ;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that I need the code to return some value and not a Boolean.

Comment: it doesn't actually return a boolean, but at least a value from the array