# Find the next highest array key

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a one liner for finding an integer key equal to or greater than a given index? To make things clear, here's an example of an array I'm working with.

```
array( 4294967295 => 'LONGTEXT'
     , 16777215   => 'MEDIUMTEXT'
     , 65535      => 'TEXT'
     , 255        => 'TINYTEXT' );
```

As some of you may recognize, these are `MySQL` column definition types. Let's say I'm given an integer `500`, how can I quickly/compactly find the next key of `65535` which maps to `'TEXT'`?

Currently I iterate the array using `foreach` (hence highest values first) and track the last key. But, due to the number of arrays and data types I'm dealing with, the function has become bloated.

Comment: maybe arrays are not the best data structure for this

Comment: @Dagon Then what would you suggest? I chose an array since they can easily be redefined in derived classes.

Comment: Whats the motivation behind requesting a one-line solution?

Comment: @MikeB I have 2 `switch` statements which I'd like to reduce to one. sth like `if ( $key = array_search( highest ) )` would help.

Comment: @Waldermort Readability and maintability go out the door when coders try to be "clever" with 1 line solutions.

Comment: @MikeB lol, I know. Hence the `compactly` in the question. Really I'm just wondering if there's an easier method than my current loop and track.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464919/php-nearest-value-from-an-array

Comment: @AzizSaleh Not a duplicate, that's finding next highest value, I'm trying to find next highest key within a pre-ordered array.

Comment: @Waldermort Always read the answers as well as the question. Many answers on that thread and many others on the column are for sorted arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is compact and should work:

```
$sizes = array_filter(array_keys($array), function($element) use ($size) { return $element >= $size; });
$array[array_pop($sizes)];
```

This will emit an undefined index error if no type large enough exists in `$array`. I really wouldn't consider it optimal - the best solution is rarely the shortest possible.

Consider using something like this, which is more robust:

```
function getType(array $types, $desiredSize) { // $types should be sorted by key asc
    foreach($array as $length => $type) {
        if($length >= $desiredSize) {
            return $type;
        }
    }

    return null; // no type large enough
}

$types = array(
        4294967295 => 'LONGTEXT',
        16777215 => 'MEDIUMTEXT',
        65535 => 'TEXT',
        255 => 'TINYTEXT');
ksort($types); // or hardcode it in asc order

echo getType($types, 500); // TEXT
```

Comment: That's exactly what I had in my mind. As a minor improvement, I would change `return null;` to `end($types);`, so it uses the largest one available. But that may not be what the OP wants. Oh well.

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure if I agree with `end()` - I guess it depends on the OP's needs. They may want to throw an exception if no type is large enough rather than just use the largest available and truncate...

Comment: This may work. Since I have to handle default values for missing sizes and arrays with only a single entry, calling this within a my `switch` would be a lot easier. Thanks :)