# Most matching array value

Tags: php, function

```
$mostmatched = function( $input to test, $array with given values)
```

The array contains diffrent numbers (10,30,50 ...) and I give an input (13) and the desired function should return the nearest value in the array (10).

Is there already a function like this? Else: Any suggestions how to achieve that?

Comment: This may have been answered:

[Answer: Nearest Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464919/php-nearest-value-from-an-array)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464919/php-nearest-value-from-an-array

Comment: sry, so I searched with wrong keywords ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($input) {
    return abs($input - $a) - abs($input - $b);
});
echo "Closest: $array[0]";
```

In other words: take the *difference* between `$input` and each value—smaller differences are closer—and *sort* the array by this. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17364128/476 if this requires explanation.

Alternatively, simply loop through the array, keep track of the last smallest difference and replace it if you find a smaller difference. I'll leave the implementation of that as an exercise for the reader.