# Find key of array based on variable value between array values

Tags: php, arrays

I need to find the **left**-near key of a base array corresponding to a variable value.

Searched value (in this case) is always between 1 and 779

Better with an example:

```
$fixedArr = [ 0, 5, 8, 20, 40, 60, 90, 135, 780 ];

$search = 42; // $result = $arr[4] -> 4;
$search = 110; // $result = $arr[6] -> 6;

$search = 134; // $result = $arr[6] -> 6;
$search = 135; // $result = $arr[7] -> 7;
```

I try with a foreach loop but with no luck, any idea??
Thanks

Comment: Search... Search... Search... Use [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)...

Comment: even if the searched value is not present in the array?

Comment: Do you want the nearest key or indexes of the array between which ?

Comment: I update the question with a new example

Comment: What the results for -1 and  800 ?

Comment: searched value is always between (in this case) 1 and 779, so no matter :)

Comment: @Mindexperiment Mine now gives the left, right, and correct value! `:)`

Comment: Your could be fine but I don't need an array as a result,just the left-key value. splash58 would be the right and fastest answer

Comment: $search = 134; // $result = $arr[6] -> 6; ---> How 134 is near to 90. it must be 135.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*searched value is always between (in this case) 1 and 779*

```
$fixedArr = [ 0, 5, 8, 20, 40, 60, 90, 135, 780 ];

$search = 42;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($fixedArr); $i++) 
   if ($search < $fixedArr[$i]) break;

echo $i-1;
```

Comment: this could be the answer but I think the count should be outside the for loop anche the if statement should be $search **>** $fixedArr[$i] . I give a try

Comment: @Mindexperiment Does mine work now?

Comment: @splash58 if you make the suggested changes your's would be the answer

Comment: @Mindexperiment why do you think so?

Comment: I'm sorry, only a note for the count outside the loop that is faster, the **<** is good. That's the right answer. Rock n roll!

Answer (score 1):

This maybe help you;

```
$fixedArr = [ 0, 5, 8, 20, 40, 60, 90,135,780 ];
//
$search = 111; // $result = $arr[4] -> 4;
//$search = 110; // $result = $arr[6] -> 6;
//
function leftORright($fixedArr,$search){
    $max = max($fixedArr)+1;
    $near = array(
    'left'=>array('key'=>'none','value'=>'none','bool'=>false),
    'right'=>array('key'=>'none','value'=>$max,'bool'=>false),
    'center'=>array('key'=>'none','value'=>'none','bool'=>false)
    );
    foreach($fixedArr as $k=>$v){
        if($v == $search){
            $near['center']['key'] = $k;
            $near['center']['value'] = $v;
        }
        if($v < $search){
            $near['left']['key'] = $k;
            $near['left']['value'] = $v;
        }
        if($v > $search and $near['right']['value'] > $v){
            $near['right']['key'] = $k;
            $near['right']['value'] = $v;
        }
    }
    //decide near left or right
    $respright = $near['right']['value'] - $search;
    $respleft = $search - $near['left']['value'] ;
    $right_left_equals = false;
    if($near['center']['value'] !== 'none'){
        $near['center']['bool'] = true;
    }else if($respleft < $respright && $near['left']['key']!='none'){
        $near['left']['bool'] = true;
    }else if($respleft > $respright && $near['right']['key']!='none'){
        $near['right']['bool'] = true;
    }else if($near['center']['value'] != 'none'){
        $near['center']['value'] = true;
    }else{
        $right_left_equals = true;
    }
    //var_dump($near);
    //Result is:
    foreach($near as $k=>$v){
        foreach($v as $k2=>$v2){
            if($v2===true){
                var_dump('near is for '.$k);
                return $v;
            }
        }
    }
    //equal for right and left
    if($right_left_equals){
        var_dump('near right left are equals');
        return array($near['right'],$near['left']);
    }
}
$result = leftORright($fixedArr,$search);
var_dump($result);
```

response:

```
string 'near is for left' (length=16)

array (size=3)
  'key' => int 6
  'value' => int 90
  'bool' => boolean true
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php):

> `array_search` — Searches the array for a given value and returns the corresponding key if successful

```
$search = array_search(42, $fixedArr); // -> 4
$search = array_search(110, $fixedArr); // -> 6
```

Your question is similar to finding the closest one:

```
<?php
    $fixedArr = [ 0, 5, 8, 20, 40, 60, 90, 135, 780 ];
    function getClosest($search, $arr) {
        $left = 0;
        foreach ($arr as $val) {
            if ($search > $val)
                $left = $val;
            elseif ($search < $val) {
                $right = $val;
                break;
            }
            else {
                $right = $val;
                break;
            }
        }
        return array($left, $right, array_search($left, $arr), array_search($right, $arr), (($search - $left) > ($right - $search) ? array_search($right, $arr) : array_search($left, $arr)));
    }
    print_r(getClosest(4, $fixedArr));
?>
```

Comment: What I don't understand? https://eval.in/487181

Comment: What if `42` is not in array??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Updated.

Comment: from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464919/php-nearest-value-from-an-array)??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Yes, updated that.

Comment: any difference from my answer??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Actually no. So I am voting your answer up. I answered first! `:P` That's the only difference.

Comment: Hey dude. sorry for negative vote. but your answer is not correct.

Comment: @Monty Thanks. Can you please explain how can I make the answer better, will surely edit it. `:)`

Comment: need the "left-near" key..

Comment: @Mindexperiment Working on it. `:)`

Comment: @Mindexperiment Updated correctly.

Comment: @Mindexperiment This now gives the left, right, and correct one's address too!

Comment: @Mindexperiment : Yes i have solution. check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : It will Work in all cases.

```
$fixedArr = [ 0, 5, 8, 20, 40, 60, 90, 135, 780 ];
$find = 14;
for ($i=0; $i < count($fixedArr); $i++) {
    if($fixedArr[$i] <= $find){
        $large[] = $fixedArr[$i];       
    }else{
        $small[] = $fixedArr[$i];
    }
}
$near1 = max($large);
$near2 = min($small);
echo "Value $find coming in between $near1 and $near2";
echo "<br>";
if($find >= ($near1 + $near2) / 2){
    echo "Closed Value is : $near2";
}else{
    echo "Closed Value is : $near1";
}
```

Output:

```
Value 14 coming in between 8 and 20
Closed Value is : 20
```