# php array search with comparison

Tags: php, arrays, search

I would like to search value in an array, but exact searched value doesn't exist.
Example :

```
$array = array (
    "A"  => 0,
    "B"  => 50,
    "C"  => 90,
    "D"  => 300,
    "E"  => 500
);

$searched_value = 80;
```

I would like to obtain B in this case.
The function I would use is the following :

```
array_search($searched_value,$array,"<=")
```

How should I proceed ?

Comment: why B and why not C? what's the criteria

Comment: check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464919/php-nearest-value-from-an-array

Comment: This isn't looking for _closest_ match, so the `abs` approach in the possible duplicate will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter the array to only include items that meet your criteria.

```
$target = 80;

$filtered = array_filter($array, function($x) use ($target) {
    return $x <= $target;
});
```

Then sort it, unless it's already sorted.

```
sort($filtered);
```

The greatest value <= your search target will be the last element.

```
$value = end($filtered);
$key = key($filtered);
```

---

To use this approach for `>=` instead, just use that operator instead of `<=` in the `array_filter` callback, and use `reset` instead of `end` to get the *first* value rather than the last one.

---

This won't be ideal for large arrays that are already sorted before applying `array_filter`, because `array_filter` will iterate every element even after it begins to find values that don't meet the criteria. In that case it's better to just use `foreach` so that you can break out of the loop as soon as you find your target.

```
$key = null;
$value = 0;

foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if ($v > $target) {
        break;
    }
    $key = $k;
    $value = $v;
}

var_dump($key, $value);
```

For smaller arrays, or arrays that aren't already sorted, this won't make much of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract your value from all array elements using `array_map` then filter values greater than `0` (zero) using `array_filter`, then take the last entry. That should be your value.

Something like this:

```
$array = array ( ... );
$searched_value = 80;

function subtract($val) {
    return $val - $searched_value;
}

function ltzero($val) {
    return $val <= 0;
}

$new_arr = array_filter(array_map('subtract', $array), 'ltzero');

// get last item or $new_arr
```

Comment: Or much simpler version by @Don't Panic: just filter out values greater than your search value :)

Answer (score -2):

use if:-

if(array_search($searched_value,$array)=="")
    echo "not found";
else 
    echo array_search($searched_value,$array);