# Compare array values and find next value in the array based on custom value (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I am trying to compare a values in array and select the next value in the array based on a selected value.

For example

```
array(05:11,05:21,05:24,05:31,05:34,05:41,05:44,05:50,05:54);
```

and if the the search value is for example `05:34`, the one that is returned to be `05:41`. If the value is `05:50`, `05:54` is returned

I did find something that might help me on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464919/find-a-matching-or-closest-value-in-an-array), but because of the `:` in my values it will not work.

Any ideas how can I get this to work?

```
function getClosest($search, $arr) {
   $closest = null;
   foreach ($arr as $item) {
      if ($closest === null || abs($search - $closest) > abs($item - $search)) {
         $closest = $item;
      }
   }
   return $closest;
}
```

**UPDATE**
Maybe I should somehow convert the values in the array in something more convenient to search within - Just a thinking.

Comment: You should wrap array values in quote

Comment: Because this is string, abs doesn't work as expected. Maybe you could convert them to something more meaningful using strtotime (or something similar) before executing foreach

Comment: Yeah, this is what I thought when I edited the post. Or maybe just removing the ":" and then if i type 0535 for example it will return 0541. Does it make sense?

Comment: @lStoilov You only want to get next item of given value?

Comment: @Mohammad, yes that's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the internal pointer array iterator -which should be better from the performance point of view than array_search- you can get the next value like this:

```
$arr = array('05:11','05:21','05:24','05:31','05:34','05:41','05:44','05:50','05:54');
function getClosest($search, $arr) {

    $item = null;
    while ($key = key($arr) !== null) {
        $current = current($arr);
        $item = next($arr);
        if (
            strtotime($current) < strtotime($search) &&
            strtotime($item) >= strtotime($search)
        ) {
            break;
        } else if (
            strtotime($current) > strtotime($search)
        ) {
            $item = $current;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $item;
}

print_r([
    getClosest('05:50', $arr),
    getClosest('05:34', $arr),
    getClosest('05:52', $arr),
    getClosest('05:15', $arr),
    getClosest('05:10', $arr),
]);
```

This will output :-

```
Array (
    [0] => 05:50
    [1] => 05:34
    [2] => 05:54
    [3] => 05:21
    [4] => 05:11
)
```

Live example https://3v4l.org/tqHOC

Comment: That's great. Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: I also had updated my answer to handle the values smaller than the very first element in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) you can find index of array item based of it value. So use it to getting index of searched item.

```
function getClosest($search, $arr) {
    return $arr[array_search($search, $arr)+1];
}
```

**Update:**

If search value not exist in array or search value is last item of array function return empty.

```
function getClosest($search, $arr) {
    $result = array_search($search, $arr);  
    return $result && $result<sizeof($arr)-1 ? $arr[$result+1] : "";
}
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/acUgt)

Comment: Thats cool, but what if you type a value which is not in the array. For example  05:35. Then it will not work

Comment: If value is `05:54` then undefined offset! Wrap it with condition. :)

Comment: @Smartpal Fixed

Answer (score 0):

First convert your array value in string because of you use the ':' in the value like

```
array('05:11','05:21','05:24','05:31','05:34','05:41','05:44','05:50','05:54');
```

Then use below code to find the next value from the array

```
function getClosest($search, $arr) {
  return $arr[array_search($search,$arr) + 1];
}
```

Comment: colon is not allowed in the array value, that's important for this question and it is not mentioned on your answer.

Comment: I also mentioned it in comment and do it in my demo

Comment: Sorry i haven't read your comment before the post, if you want then i will provide the screenshot of the code that i made for this question :)

And it's common and easiest technique to find the value in the array.