# Determining nearest digit?

Tags: php

So given this array:

`$stack = [
 100,
 200,
 300,
 400,
 500,
 600,
 700
]`

What is the best way, given some arbitrary number, for example `$needle = 78`, to find 'nearest' number from the stack. In this case it would be 100.

I have algorithm in mind, where I loop through all numbers, and do determine it eventually.

But this for some reason feels, like it has some nice one liner solution that I am just not aware of. So is my feeling correct, is there such one liner?

Comment: Do you have any constraints? Such as, "`$stack` is always sorted" or "all numbers that end in `00`"? If not, then iterating and remembering the closest is the best there is.

Comment: Asking about a "best way" is very broad, with no single *right* answer. If you have a problem with what you've coded, please edit your question to show what you've tried, issues/errors you're running into, etc. But as written, there's no code, just an ask for the community to solve this for you. And, unfortunately, that's off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: There is no one-liner solution (regardless if the array is or isn't pre-sorted). The amount of code you need, however, is quite small though. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464919/find-a-matching-or-closest-value-in-an-array

Comment: Yeah I had something like what you reference in mind. I just thought that maybe there is some standart function available for this. Thanks everyone! :)

Comment: To follow the "letter" of the question you could always do something like `$result = array_reduce($stack, function($carry, $item) use ($needle) { return abs($carry-$needle) < abs($item-$needle) ? $carry : $item; });` but readability wise it's pretty horrible compared to a straight forward function (and you'd need a pretty wide screen to have it fit one line :))) )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a matching or closest value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464919/find-a-matching-or-closest-value-in-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a function to check for value e.g.:

```
function findClose($needle, $stack) {
   $close= null;
   foreach ($arr as $value) {
     if ($close == null) {
          $close = $value;
     }

     if ( !is_null( $close ) && abs($value - $close) > abs($value - $search)) {
       $close= $value;
     }
  }
  return $close;
}
```

and call this function with your value.

```
echo findClose(160, $stack);
```

will give you the result you want.

Hope it helps.