# Round number up to closest value in array

Tags: php

I've created an array with 'maximum' values in.

```
$management = array(
    '100' => '1',
    '500' => '2',
    '1000' => '3',
);
```

And created a loop to find the closest value, rounding it up.

```
$speed = 10;

$r= '';
sort($management);
foreach($management as $mgmt => $name) {
    if($mgmt >= $speed) {
        $r= $name;
    }
}
$r= end($management);
```

So, where the `$speed` is `10`, it should pick up the array key `100` and if it was `100` it should still pickup `100` but if the speed was `200`, it would pickup `500`

The above is picking up `500` when the `$speed` is `10` though.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a matching or closest value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464919/find-a-matching-or-closest-value-in-an-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of problems with your code. Firstly, the call to [`sort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) rewrites all the keys of the `$management` array which you are using for the comparison; you need to use [`ksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) instead to sort by the keys instead of the values. Secondly, since the keys are in ascending order, once one is greater than the `$speed` value, they all will be, so you need to `break` from the loop once you find a higher value. Try this instead:

```
$r= '';
ksort($management);
foreach($management as $mgmt => $name) {
    if($mgmt >= $speed) {
        $r= $name;
        break;
    }
}
echo $r;
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/nO58V)

Answer (score 0):

this is an example on how you can do it :

```
$array = array(1, 10, 100, 200, 400, 500, 1000);

public function getArrayRoundUp($array, $number) {

sort($array);
foreach ($array as $a) {

if ($a >= $number) return $a;
}
return end($array);
}

$value = 950;
$nearest = getArrayRoundUp($array, $value);
//the expect result will be 1000
echo $nearest;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function

```
function find(array $array, $search)
{
    $last = null; // return value if $array array is empty

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($key >= $search) {
            return $key; // found it, return quickly
        }
        $last = $key; // keep the last key thus far
    }

    return $last;
}
```

Tested and Working:-

```
echo find($management, 100); // Will result 100
echo find($management, 200); //Will result 500
```