# PHP Find closest percentile for a numbered variable

Tags: php, math

I have 3 percentile values calculated that are stored in variables like this:

```
$twentyfive = '55';
$fifty = '80';
$seventyfive = '95';
```

Each user on my website has a value from 20-100 stored in the variable: $percentile and I am trying to match their number closest to one of the three variables above so I can say: You are part of the X percentile.

For example, if a users $percentile value was '35' they would be matched with $twentyfive since that's the closest variable to their number.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: What will the range for giving the user these percentiles? Like $twentyfive : 20 to ?, $fifty : ? to ? So on

Answer (score 0):

```
if($percentile < 67.5){
   echo $twentyfive
}  elseif($percentile > 67.5 && $percentile < 87.7){
   echo $fifty
}else{
   echo $seventyfive
}
```

Comment: if you dont want to hardcode values get the difference and devide it by 2 and add to the value

Answer (score 0):

If the values of the 3 variables can change you can use this.  There may be a more concise way, but this should work.

```
//Set users percentile
$user_percentile = 35;
$user_percentile_category = 25;

switch ($user_percentile) {
    case $user_percentile <= $twentyfive:
        $user_percentile_category = '25';
        break;
    case ($user_percentile - $twentyfive) < $fifty - $user_percentile:
        $user_percentile_category = '25';
        break;
    case ($user_percentile - $twentyfive) >= $fifty - $user_percentile:
        $user_percentile_category = '50';
        break;
    case ($user_percentile - $fifty) < $seventyfive - $user_percentile:
        $user_percentile_category = '50';
        break;
    case ($user_percentile - $fifty) >= $seventyfive - $user_percentile:
        $user_percentile_category = '75';
        break;
    default:
        $user_percentile_category = '75';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for this:

```
function getClosest($search, $arr) {
   $closest = null;
   foreach ($arr as $item) {
      if ($closest === null || abs($search - $closest) > abs($item - $search)) {
         $closest = $item;
      }
   }
   return $closest;
}

$collection = [55,80,95];
$searchValue = 88;

echo getClosest($searchValue, $collection);
```

Hope it helps you. I have taken the reference from [Find a matching or closest value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464919/find-a-matching-or-closest-value-in-an-array)

Cheers!!