# Nearest array element by key in reverse order

Tags: php, arrays

I have custom code where I get nearest user from array by array key:

```
$users = [
    "4" => "John",
    "7" => "Alex",
    "13" => "Smith",
    "95" => "Taylor"
];

$id = 9;

$nearestUserByIdInReverseOrder = false;

foreach($users as $userId => $name) {
    if($id >= $userId) {
        $nearestUserByIdInReverseOrder = $name;
    }
}

echo $nearestUserByIdInReverseOrder;
```

When I change var `$id` to 3 or smaller number then don't get result. How to get first element of array when `$id` smaller then it. And can be shorted or optimized code if I've incorrect logic operation in my code? Maybe this possible without looping.

Here is [demo](https://3v4l.org/OelF2)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "nearest" mean in your case, and give a few examples? e.g. an `$id` of 12 *or* 14 would yield `Smith` as a result?

Comment: What do you expect if your `$id` is equally between 2 `$users`? For exampe, say you have users `20` and `22` and `$id` is `21`?

Comment: When current id 12 then result equal to `Alex` and when 14 `Smith`. You can see my demo [code](https://3v4l.org/OelF2)

Comment: Downvoted for unclear question (specially because of not mentioning "order" in your expectation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the first value in your array if `$id` is less than any of the array keys, you can initialise `$nearestUserByIdInReverseOrder` to the first element in the array using [`reset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php):

```
$users = [
    "4" => "John",
    "7" => "Alex",
    "13" => "Smith",
    "95" => "Taylor"
];

$id = 3;

$nearestUserByIdInReverseOrder = reset($users);
foreach($users as $userId => $name) {
    if($id >= $userId) {
        $nearestUserByIdInReverseOrder = $name;
    }
}

echo $nearestUserByIdInReverseOrder;
```

Output:

```
John
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/VdOuD)

Note that for this (or your original code) to work, the keys must be in increasing numerical order. If they might not be, [`ksort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) the array first:

```
ksort($users);
```

Comment: But, sir, if you enter ``94`` for an example, the nearest of ``94`` is ``95`` and this will return ``Smith`` instead of ``Taylor``, isn't it?

Comment: @OMiShah OP wants the closest name below the `$id` value. See their demo code and also their comment on values to return when `$id=12` or `$id=14`.

Comment: Hmm, then it's okay. I had asked to clear my general query, don't mind :)

Comment: @OMiShah no problem at all.

Comment: This answer also results in `Alex` for `$id = 12`

Comment: @MLF that is what OP wants, see their comments to the question

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation you want to reverse the comparison logic.  Also, you want to `break` out of the loop when you have found the key that is greater, or else you will always get the greatest number:

```
foreach($users as $userId => $name) {
    if($userId > $id) {
        $nearestUserByIdInReverseOrder = $name;
        break;
    }
}
```

I have removed the `=` as that would return `4` for `$id = 4` instead of `7`.  If that is not the desired behavior then add it back.

If the array is not guaranteed to be in ascending order of keys then you need to sort first:

```
ksort($users);
```

Comment: When id 14 result must be `Smith` instead of `Taylor` as your code result.

Comment: Then your question is unclear _How to get first element of array **when $id smaller then it**._  14 is not smaller than 13.

Comment: People learn from mistakes usually. If you see my mistake please correct me then.

Comment: The mistake is that the question is not clear on what you want.  What if `$id = 12`?  Do you still want `Smith` or do you want `Alex`.

Comment: When 12 result must be `Alex`. Why your not see to my demo code on question and try any number and see to results?

Answer (score 0):

```
function findClosest($array, $index) {
    ksort($array);
    $idx = array_keys($array)[0];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($key > $index) return $array[$idx];
        $idx = $key;
    }
}

$users = [
    "13" => "Smith",
    "4" => "John",
    "7" => "Alex",
    "95" => "Taylor"
];

$id = 3;

echo findClosest($users, $id);
```

Comment: if you pass $id = 12 and run the code, it will return ``Alex`` instead of ``Smith``

Comment: @OMiShah From OP: "_When current id 12 then result equal to `Alex` and when 14 `Smith`._"

Comment: @OMiShah That's OK because the greatest index before 12 is 7 and 13 is greater than 12, so it shouldn't return that. That's the basic meaning of "order" in a sorted list.

Answer (score -1):

You could use array_keys() (props to [Jeto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965834/jeto)) on the array, search for the closest number in that ([this for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464919/find-a-matching-or-closest-value-in-an-array)) and then grab the name based on that.

This would work and the logic is pretty simple, although there may be better solutions. I'm sure *someone* can use it at some point for something :)